# How render input fields label and text boxes in table format in angular 7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to populate input fields label and text boxes dynamically in html form in table format. Each row consists 3 columns,  should populate 3 text boxes in different cells in my angular7 app.

Eg:

First row -> Label1: textbox1 Label2: textbox2 Labe31: textbox3
Second row ...

Comment: use css flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Angular Material Tables! Gives very clean syntax in HTML for defining columns.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: How about displaying input filed text boxes dynamically based on api response in HTML form ?